# How can i querying inheritance class with linq to EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

The solution is getting data from "Node" class but "Node" class couldn't have some attribute

Example:

```
public class Node
   {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public long PreviousQuestionID { get; set; }
        public long NextQuestionID { get; set; }
        public long SurveyID { get; set; }
   }


public class Student: Node
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public long QuestionItemID { get; set; }
        public long AnswerSetID { get; set; }
}
```

EF generated only 1 table. Could you have any idea to query with linq? please?

because if i first select in model "Node" it couldn't see "Student" when i work it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose wether to create a table per type or a table per hierarchy, by just adding `[Table("Name")]` to your classes.

To query such a class you can use the following statements:

```
myContext.Nodes.OfType<Student>().Where(s => s.Name.Contains("abc"));
```

Comment: Thank you. So i used this for solve my solution

from n in this.genericRepository.DbContext.Nodes.OfType<Student>()

Comment: Independent of this here @Anatolii Gabuza has a good point, too

Comment: I prefer using `Nodes.Where(node => node is Student)`. I don't know about efficiency but I like the readability.

Comment: Yeah, but OfType also does a cast for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Node` is created only for design purposes you should have `Students` table. In such case there is no problem to query `Students` table and access Node's properties.
If you need to store both `Student` and `Node` as a separate entities - specify two tables in configuration:

```
public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
public DbSet<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
```